# Reconstruct PHP array to fit data into html table correctly

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to display data that shows the count for each month for locations in Jan-December.

I wrote the query to get the necessary data from the server but when I display it in the view in my table the layout for the data, doesn't look the way I want it to look like in my table. I believe I have to reconstruct the array that I wrote in the query for the right format first and then I can display it in my table?

Right now, the data that comes back from the server looks like so

```js
<table id="registeredTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Locations</th>
        <th>January</th>
        <th>Feburary</th>
        <th>March</th>
        <th>April</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>June</th>
        <th>July</th>
        <th>August</th>
        <th>September</th>
        <th>October</th>
        <th>November</th>
        <th>December</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
      foreach($selectAllmonthlylocations as $item) {
        echo '
    <tr>
      <td>'.$item["locations"].'</td>
      <td>'.$item["Total"].'</td>
    </tr>
        ';
  }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So my question is how can I format my array properly to display it in my table how I want?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Austin_Domestic
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-03
            [Total] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Austin_International
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-25
            [Total] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => BayArea_Domestic
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-16
            [Total] => 192
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => BayArea_International
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-05
            [Total] => 28
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Bengaluru_Domestic
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-10
            [Total] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Bengaluru_International
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-05
            [Total] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Cork
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-02
            [Total] => 31
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => CulverCity
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-10
            [Total] => 3
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Denver
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-10
            [Total] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Hyderabad
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-05
            [Total] => 3
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => London
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-02
            [Total] => 10
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Macau
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-17
            [Total] => 1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Munich
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-02
            [Total] => 6
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Sacramento_Domestic
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-04
            [Total] => 1
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Shanghai
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-12
            [Total] => 2
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Singapore
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-03
            [Total] => 8
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Sydney
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-21
            [Total] => 1
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Tokyo
            [DateAdded] => 2018-01-04
            [Total] => 3
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Austin_Domestic
            [DateAdded] => 2018-02-01
            [Total] => 31
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Austin_International
            [DateAdded] => 2018-02-19
            [Total] => 2
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => Bangkok
            [DateAdded] => 2018-02-07
            [Total] => 1
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => BayArea_Domestic
            [DateAdded] => 2018-02-08
            [Total] => 165
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [usergroup] => BayArea_International
            [DateAdded] => 2018-02-12
            [Total] => 29
        )
```

**Here is my code:**

```
$selectallmonthlysql = 'SELECT locations, DateAdded, COUNT(*) as Total
                    FROM testserverdataSignup
                    WHERE DateAdded > "2017-12-31"
                    GROUP BY month(DateAdded), locations';

    $selectAllmonthlystmt = $dbo->prepare($selectallmonthlysql);

    $selectAllmonthlystmt->execute();

    $selectAllmonthlylocations = $selectAllmonthlystmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Screenshot of what the table currently looks like: I want the individual count for each location to correlate to the month and go across instead of down

[image]

Comment: It would be easier if you use `var_export` instead of `print_r` to output the array, `var_export` give output that can just be plugged into a sandbox, where `print_r` requires modification to test with it.

Comment: February instead of Feburary, just saying.  Not that I am the Grammar or Spelling police, because I fail at both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change your query

```
$selectallmonthlysql = '
SELECT
    locations,
    MONTHNAME(DateAdded) AS month,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM    
    testserverdataSignup
WHERE
    DateAdded > "2017-12-31"
GROUP BY month(DateAdded),locations';
```

I lowercased `Total` to `total`, its something that was irritating me.

With PDO then you can do

```
$results = $selectAllmonthlystmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
foreach($results AS $location => $row ){
```

`FETCH_GROUP` is poorly documented but this will organize your data with the first column as the Key of the nested array, in this case the location, which is exactly what we want.  One of the reasons I use PDO instead of that other DB library I won't mention by name but it starts with `MySql` and ends with `i`.

[MONTHNAME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)  (click for documentation) will return the full name of the month like "February" which although is not necessary (just a number would do) its much easier to read when outputting the array for debugging.

You'll wind up with something like this

```
//canned example data, notice one month is out of order and the big gap
// between February to October, this is to show it properly orders and
//fills those in. Always best to test this situations.
$result = array(
   "Austin_Domestic" => array(

       0 => Array(
            "month" => "February",
            "total" => 5
        ),
       1 => Array(
            "month" => "January",
            "total" => 15
        ),
        2 => Array(
            "month" => "October",
            "total" => 8
        ),

    ),
);
//$results = $selectAllmonthlystmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

//then putting it all together

//we'll need the months in an array anyway so we can saves some space with them in the HTML  too.
$months = array(    
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
)

?>

<table id="registeredTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Locations</th>
        <?php foreach($months as $month){
             //Output the names of the months
             echo "<th>{$month}</th>\n";
        } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
        foreach( $result as $location => $rows ){
             echo "<tr>\n";
             echo "<td>{$location}</td>\n";
            //simplifies lookup by month (indexes are correlated)
            //it returns column 'month' from $rows as a flat array.
            //we can save ourselves an external loop by doing this "trick"
            $m = array_column($rows, 'month');
            //for example, in the case: [0=>February,1=>January,2=>October]
            //because this is created from $rows, with a natural number index
            //we can simply do array_search on $m to get the index we need in $rows (see below)
            foreach($months as $month){
                $index = array_search($month, $m);
                if(false === $index){
                    echo "<td>0</td>\n";
                }else{
                   echo "<td>{$rows[$index]['total']}</td>\n"; 
                }                 
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output (I did format it to look a bit nicer):

```
<table id="registeredTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Locations</th>
            <th>January</th>
            <th>February</th>
            <th>March</th>
            <th>April</th>
            <th>May</th>
            <th>June</th>
            <th>July</th>
            <th>August</th>
            <th>September</th>
            <th>October</th>
            <th>November</th>
            <th>December</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Austin_Domestic</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/16226894949d05bb50046b44e74b64a493729509)

One note and benefit of using an array for the months is you spelled `Feburary` wrong it should be `February` something I've been guilty of many many times.

The only real downside to this, is the month name has to match the month name returned from the DB, which shouldn't be an issue if they are spelled correctly (which is how I found the mistake).  Otherwise this can applied to the month as a number just as easily, same idea.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you this worked however, I had to change my echo statement to this as the array was an stdClass object i believe? `echo "<td>{$rows[$index]->total}</td>";`

Comment: ok, I was just going off the data posted in the question.  You used the `FETCH_GROUP`? I have my PDO default to `FETCH_ASSOC`, that could be why because 99% of the time I want an associative array when I do sql manually.  And setting the default fetch mode means it always returns an associative array if you don't specify.  As I said FETCH_GROUP is poorly documented so it may be that in your case it did an object which is the default (I think) where mine defaults to an array?  That is my guess at least .... lol

Comment: Yeah I put in the `FETCH_GROUP` it's fine. I'm still trying to learn php so thank you for the help I think i need more practice with organizing array structures properly. It took me awhile to understand the code.

Comment: Well to explain, first they should be grouped (in the array) by what you want the row to be (location), this way when you loop over the top elements, you can set your `tr` then the next grouping should be by the `month` which sets your `td`. But to group that would require a pre-processing loop over the data, so I short cut that by using array_column, this returns an array with all the months. In this case its from the nested location group.  Because this is naturally indexed by PHP we can use array_search to get the index and it will be the same as the nested element that date was pulled from

Comment: This gives us an effective way of looking up the Month we need, so we can loop over the months, search for that month and do the `td` this method also avoids holes in the data when months are missing, because we loop of the month array, we can still put our `td` in even if no data was returned from the DB.

Comment: array_column, is like a pivot, instead of giving you a row with columns in it, it takes one column from each nested array and gives you that.  Like I said because these are indexed, `0,1,2` etc in order for the nested array, when that array is created the indexes match the array it came from, because they are also created in the order of `0,1,2`, so its the same.  It's a nice shortcut to make array search work on a nest array, by giving it a flat array.

Comment: Okay i think i understand thank you for the clarification of the explanation. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure it's just something that comes with experience.  You get to the point were you can run small pieces of code in your head .... lol

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change the query to return `MONTH(DateAdded)` instead of the whole date, since that's how your output table is organized:

```
$selectallmonthlysql = 'SELECT locations, MONTH(DateAdded) AS month, COUNT(*) as Total
                FROM testserverdataSignup
                WHERE DateAdded > "2017-12-31"
                GROUP BY month, locations';
```

Then you should reorganize the array into nested arrays:

```
array(location1 => array(month1 => total1, month2 => total2, ...),
      location2 => array(month1 => total1, month2 => total2, ...),
      ...)
```

This code will do that:

```
$groupedData = array();
while ($selectAllmonthlystmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $groupedData[$row['locations']][$row['month']] = $row['Total'];
}
```

Then you can use nested loops when creating the table. The outer loop creates the rows, the inner loop is for the cells in the row.

```
foreach ($groupedData as $location => $locationData) {
    echo "<tr><td>$location</td>";
    for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo isset($locationData[$month]) ? $locaitonData[$month] : 0;
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: How about Group by locations first and then month?.

Comment: @Sal The order of grouping doesn't matter.